# Polygon not pouring over net tie pads in Altium

Tags: altium, ground-plane, jumper

I am working with net ties in altium to link different ground signals. My net ties seem to work, no drc error, and I can link traces between them and objects of the same net.

If I try to pour a polygon over them however, nothing happens. I even created a component class to have direct connect for my net ties. My polygons are set to pour over all same net objects and it works well for anything else... the only problem is my net tie and I dont know wht is causing this behaviour?

[image]

Here you see the net tie, joined to a copper region on its left side (works) but the gnd plane polygon cannot pour over its right pad!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does seem to do that. A bug I guess.

If you place a stub trace at the pad with the common net name to the polygon it will pour over the stub.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this solution isn't working for me. The reason being is I have a rule on the trace width. I have a net that is carrying a large amperage on one side of the net tie, and I can't fit a trace wide enough to carry it, so I'm doing a poly pour instead. The net on the other side of the net tie is a much lower current, and that's why I'm doing the net tie. If I do this method, using a stub trace, it tells me that the trace isn't wide enough...

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the polygon pour

Change the polygon pour to pour over same net objects

[image]

This will only work if the net tie and the polygon pour have the same net name, so make sure the polygon pour has the same name as the net tie (in connected to net

If its not that then it's probably some weird rule in your DRC (Design Rule Checker ) rules

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP and I have "Pour Over All Same Net Objects" and it still doesn't work. It just avoids the whole net tie, even the part with the same name.